# Is it possible to add an empty dictionary to a python class?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, parameters, self

Is it possible to add an empty dictionary with self parameters into a class so that I can add elements to it later with a defined method?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. `self.my_dict = dict()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an empty dictionary is just like adding any other variable:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.empty_dict = {}
```

Comment: And if I am using the dataclass library?

Comment: You just enter the dictionary variable name equals {}