# What is the proper way to create a class instance with an empty dictionary and/or list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237338/is-it-possible-to-add-an-empty-dictionary-to-a-python-class) suggests I am creating my empty dictionary the correct way.

```
class Board:
    def __init(self):
        self.pot = 0
        self.activePlayer = 1
        self.activePlayers = 4
        self.passedPlayers = 0
        self.firstHand = True
        self.lastCardsPlayedList = []
        self.lastCardsPlayedDict = {}

    def playCard(self, cardInt, cardPic):
        self.lastCardsPlayedDict[cardInt] = cardPic
        self.lastCardsPlayedList.append(cardInt)
        self.lastCardsPlayedList.sort()
```

I create an instance of my class

```
b = Board()
```

but when I go to call it...

```
b.playCard(1, cardPic)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Board' object has no attribute 'lastCardsPlayedDict'
```

Comment: __init(self) -> __init__(self)

Comment: That was it. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method needs to be `__init__` not `__init`:

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self): #notice the change here
        self.pot = 0
        self.activePlayer = 1
        self.activePlayers = 4
        self.passedPlayers = 0
        self.firstHand = True
        self.lastCardsPlayedList = []
        self.lastCardsPlayedDict = {}

    def playCard(self, cardInt, cardPic):
        self.lastCardsPlayedDict[cardInt] = cardPic
        self.lastCardsPlayedList.append(cardInt)
        self.lastCardsPlayedList.sort()
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you sir.

Comment: @MechEE No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Silly Mistake...your **init** method is not defined correctly.

Here is the corrected code.

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pot = 0
        self.activePlayer = 1
        self.activePlayers = 4
        self.passedPlayers = 0
        self.firstHand = True
        self.lastCardsPlayedList = []
        self.lastCardsPlayedDict = {}

    def playCard(self, cardInt, cardPic):
        self.lastCardsPlayedDict[cardInt] = cardPic
        self.lastCardsPlayedList.append(cardInt)
        self.lastCardsPlayedList.sort()


b = Board()
b.playCard(1, 'cardPic')

print(b)
```

Comment: You got it. Thank you sir.